# Probability of Finding Two Matching Subsequences in a Sequence

Tags: probability, sequence-analysis, overlapping-data

I'm currently studying **DNA sequencing** and am trying to find a formula which gives the probability that a subsequence of length $k$ appears **twice** in a sequence of $L$ bases (characters); this is pretty much a **substring problem**.

The sequence consists of four possible characters: 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T' representing nucleobases which can occur in the sequence essentially at random, i.e. random positions and with an arbitrary number of occurrences.

I'm trying to work out the probability of a data structure reaching a certain size based upon matching subsequences and to do this I need to know the probability of finding two matching subsequences of length $k$.

What I have so far is that the probability of finding a specific $k$-length sequence would be:

$$P = \frac{1}{4^k}$$

and so the probability of finding this sequence twice would be:

$$P = \left(\frac{1}{4^k}\right)^2$$

However this doesn't take into account the length ($L$) of the sequence **or** the fact that the last $k-1$ characters of the subsequence from the first offset match the first $k-1$ characters at the second offset.

I cannot figure out how, **or if**, the length and the overlap would affect the formula.

Any help would be appreciated.